# How do I stop a function running again when I dont want it to? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, web

Lots of things are not right in my js code.
When I click "Show" more than once, #box-1 just keeps moving further and further down. Same thing's happening for #box-2 when I clock "Hide" more than once. How do I stop this from happening?

I'd also like to add, how to I make the boxes "fade" when it shows and hides? I can only seem to make it work when it's showing.
Also i don't want to use a toggle button, I want to use 2 buttons because I'm experimenting on something.

Here's a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vr1u0wzu/55/)

Thank you for your time :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#hide').click(function(){
    $('#box1').hide().animate({'top': '-=155px', opacity: 0}, 500);
    $('#box2').show().animate({'top': '+=155px', opacity: 1}, 500); 
})

$('a#show').click(function(){
    $('#box1').show().animate({'top': '+=155px', opacity: 1}, 500);       
    $('#box2').hide().animate({'top': '-=155px', opacity: 0}, 500);
}) });
```

EDIT:

I got the code working the way I wanted to all thanks to you guys!
All your answers isnt exactly what I was looking for, but with all of your answers, I definitely got it working. So thank you very much to all of you for answering and helping me out :) I really appreciate it.

Here's the updated JSFiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/vr1u0wzu/83/

Thank you once again people. Cheers!

Comment: Add an if statement to only execute the code if the box is hidden / shown respectively.

Comment: your first problem is that you increment/decrement your values... the second is that you want the other box to fadeout instead of hiding....

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
function hideIt() {
  $('#box1').hide().animate({'top': '-=155px', opacity: 0}, 500);
  $('#box2').show().animate({'top': '+=155px', opacity: 1}, 500); 
  $('a#show').one('click', showIt);
}
function showIt() {
  $('#box1').show().animate({'top': '+=155px', opacity: 1}, 500);       
  $('#box2').hide().animate({'top': '-=155px', opacity: 0}, 500);
  $('a#hide').one('click', hideIt);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#hide').one('click', hideIt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#hide').click(function(){
    $('#box1').fadeOut();
    $('#box2').show().animate({'top': '155px', opacity: 1}, 500); 
    })

    $('a#show').click(function(){
    $('#box1').show().animate({'top': '155px', opacity: 1}, 500);       
    $('#box2').fadeOut();
  })
 });
```

hope this helps you.. don't forget to upcheck if it is what you're looking for.. =)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want only one box to be displayed at a time. Here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/vr1u0wzu/55/.

If you are not able to understand, please mention your doubt. I have used CSS classes to achieve the fadein and fadeout. This is the simplest way to do it. Although you can use `.show()`, `.hide()`,`.fadeOut()`, `.fadeIn()` jquery functions to achieve the same.

The reason why the box kept moving down is because you were not resetting it's top to 0px;